# Issues while downloading document from Sharepoint using JAVA

Tags: java, sharepoint-2007

I am trying to download a file from Sharepoint 2007 sp2 document library using GetItem method of the Copy webservice. I am facing the following issues :

1. In the local instance ( Windows Vista ) I can save only 10.5 Kb of any file. The webservice is returning only 10.5 Kb of data for any file.
2. On the production server, I am able to List the documents using some credentials but when I am trying to download a document using the same credentials I get a 401 : Unauthorized message. I can download the document using the Sharepoint website successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to download the file successfully by writing the data in the response OutputStream and setting the response header as

`response.setHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + downloadFileName + "\"");`